# OpenGL anisotropic filtering support, contradictory check results

Tags: opengl

When checking if anisotropic filtering is supported, I get contradictory results.

```
if(glewIsSupported("GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic") || GLEW_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic) {
        std::cout << "support anisotropic" << std::endl;
    }

GLfloat max;
glGetFloatv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &max);
std::cout << max << std::endl;
```

The output for this section on my machine is:

```
16
```

So seemingly an anisotropic filtering of 16 is supported, but `glewIsSupported` as well as the glew extension string say the opposite.

Is checking for `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT` enough and is the glew check wrong, or is something different going on?

Comment: Is GLEW properly initialized when you call those functions?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, `glewInit` with `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE` returns `GLEW_OK`.

Comment: @JustinMeiners Which one do you mean with string? I am fairly sure that my graphics card supports anisotropic filtering.

Comment: @AdamS You say both `glewIsSupported` and the OpenGL extensions string says that doesnt exist correct? If so I would trust those, I don't think `glGetFloatv` is guaranteed to not give you some value.

Comment: @JustinMeiners the conditions in the if statement are both based on GLEW

Comment: log this glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);

Comment: @JustinMeiners http://pastebin.com/3ptc01vz GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic is apparently supported.

Comment: @AdamS wow this must be a bug in glew. Well thats the thing to trust, perhaps write your own extension chec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a [known bug in glew](http://sourceforge.net/p/glew/bugs/174/?page=0) where `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` is used even in an OpenGL 3+ context instead of `glGetStringi` that replaced the extension querying in OpenGL 3+.

So until patched, extension querying must be [done manually](http://pastebin.com/3ptc01vz).

Comment: This is not _exactly_ a bug, but a consequence of OpenGL's legacy. This comes down to a chicken and egg sort of situation. `glGetStringi (...)` is only exposed through extensions on platforms that are not OpenGL 3.0 native; now, to determine whether or not this extension is present you must first query the extension string. In an OpenGL 3.x core context, it is invalid to query the `GL_EXTENSIONS` string the old way. This is yet another one of those paradoxical situations that arises, like having to create a render context on Win32 so you can load the extension(s) to create a render context...

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to solve the chicken and egg problem is to call glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) and check glGetError() for GL_INVALID_ENUM. This should only be raised in case GL_EXTENSIONS is not available. If you encounter this error, try glGetStringi. Don't forget to check the errors here, too. GLEW doesn't (as of version 1.10 :/ ).