# Getting Exception thrown for glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHight);

Tags: c++, exception, opengl

```cpp
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    //INIT GLFW
    glfwInit();

    //CREATE WINDOW

    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
    int framebufferWidth = 0;
    int framebufferHight = 0;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT,"Title", NULL, NULL);

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &framebufferWidth, &framebufferHight);

    glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHight);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);//IMPORTIANT!!

    //INIT GLEW (NEEDS WINDOW AND OPENGL CONTEXT)
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 

    >//Error

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::MAIN.CPP::GLEW_INIT_FAILED" << "\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    //MAIN LOOP
    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //UPDATE INPUT ---


        //UPDATE ---

        //DRAW ---
        //Clear

        //Draw

        //End Draw
    }

    //END OF PROGAM
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

`glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHight);` is giving me

> Unhandled exception at >0x00007FF704D6E7D9 in OpenzGL4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading >location >0x0000000000000348.

when I run it.

Comment: You probably forgot to check for errors, this looks like a null-pointer being used.

Answer (score 3):

For any OpenGL instruction is required a valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). Hence [`glfwMakeContextCurrent`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__context.html#ga1c04dc242268f827290fe40aa1c91157) hast to be invoked before any OpneGL instruction:

```cpp
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT,"Title", NULL, NULL);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // <----- ADD

glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &framebufferWidth, &framebufferHight);

glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHight); 

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // <----- DELETE
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Rabbid76 already wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112447/2327517), there is another problem in your code:

> ```
> glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHight);
>
> glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);//IMPORTIANT!!
>
> //INIT GLEW (NEEDS WINDOW AND OPENGL CONTEXT) 
> glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
>
> >//Error
>
> if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
>     std::cout << "ERROR::MAIN.CPP::GLEW_INIT_FAILED" << "\n";
>     glfwTerminate(); }
> ```

Since you use the GLEW OpenGL loader, every `gl...()` Function name is actually remapped as a preprocessor macro to a function pointer, and `glewInit` will query all those function pointers (and that needs an active OpenGL context, so it can't be done before the `glfwMakeContextCurrent`). So it is not enough to move the `glViewport` after the `glfwMakeContextCurrent`, you must also move it after `glewInit`.

And there is a second issue with this code: the `glewExperimental =  GL_TRUE` is an [evil hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619644/2327517) for a bug in GLEW 1.x with OpenGL core profiles, and it's use can't be discouraged enough. Just update to GLEW 2.x or another loader which is compatible with OpenGL core profile contexts.